# nginx authbasic for whole site fails

Tags: php, security, nginx

I have this in my server config

```
location / {

            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            auth_basic  "protected";
            auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

When I call my domain or any subfolder, e.g.
http://example.com/folder/
protection works

but when I call my domain incl. file-name, e.g.
http://example.com/index.php
I don't need to enter any credentials and can just bypass authbasic.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Move auth_basic and auth_basic_user_file out of the location block, so that they take place in the server block instead. This way these directive will affect all locations, not only /.

Comment: how can I give you credit for correct answer?